# How to launch a Docker container that i've got from another person?

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I am a Docker-newbie and I've got a project from another developer including a Dockerfile. This shall give me the Virtual Machine to continue work with the (nodeJS-) project inside this project folder.

Docker is already installed on my machine.
How can I launch this container now?

I've read about a command

```
sudo docker run -name my_first_instance
```

but i can't find any container name in the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dockerfile` will create an `image` for you that you can launch `containers` from. this being said , Follow this:

Create a folder.

Copy `dockerfile` in the folder

cd into the folder execute the following command:

```
docker build -t <your desired image name> .
```

This will create an `image` using directives in the `dockerfile` in the current folder.

Now launch a `container` from the image.

```
docker run -d --name <your container name> <imagename from previous step> <optional startup commands>
```

Useful `docker` commands:

You can expose ports in the previous command using `-p` switch.

You can list Images via `docker images`

You can list running containers via `docker ps`

you can list running + exited containers via `docker ps -a`

Comment: Thank you very much! What could be the reason, that "docker ps -a" returns this docker container with status "exited (1) 42 seconds ago"?

Comment: take the ID from `docker ps` and do `docker inspect <ID>` for more info

Answer (score 0):

have a look at

https://hub.docker.com/_/node/

it is the official repository for NodeJS docker images

If you want some docker images based on NodeJS, you will need to pull them `docker pull my_node_image`

Then you can launch one with such a command

`docker run -it --rm --name my-running-script -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app node:4 node your-daemon-or-script.js`

The Dockerfile is just the recipe to build a docker image, for Nginx, Mysql, MongoDb, Redis, Wordpress, Spotify, atop, htop...

If `docker images` shows nothing, it means you have not yet pulled any docker image.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. He's asking how he can turn a Dockerfile that's part of the project into a running container. The fact that it happens to be a node application isn't really relevant.

Comment: Farhad's answer is about it.